# Why StringBuilder Replace is not replacing old value string with a new string?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Logger class I'm trying to switch and replace between two strings but it's never changing them.  I used a breakpoint, and it does get to these lines but never change the strings.

At the top of the class:

`public class Logger { private StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();`

then inside the method LogDownloadCompleted I'm trying to make the replacing:

`

```
public void LogDownloadCompleted(bool isSuccess, TimeSpan elapsedTime, bool isCancelled)
{
    this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Update elapsed time when the download completes
    if (!isCancelled)
    {
        logBuilder.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}");
    }
    else
    {
        logBuilder.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download Cancelled");
    }
    logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Elapsed Time]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}");
    logBuilder.AppendLine($"[End Time]: {DateTime.Now}");
    logBuilder.AppendLine(); // Add a space line between download logs
}
```

`

it keeps showing the left side:  $"[Status] Downloading in progress"

usage example in form1:

`private Logger logger = new Logger();`

and then in some places for example:

`

```
private void DownloadManager_DownloadCompleted(object? sender, DownloadingCore.DownloadeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isCancelled)
    {
        logger.LogDownloadCompleted(e.IsSuccess, _elapsedTime, isCancelled);
    }

    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    _stopwatch.Stop();

    if (e.IsSuccess && downloadsCounter > 0)
    {
        downloadsCounter--;
    }

    if(isCancelled && fileSavePath != null)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileSavePath))
        {
            File.Delete(fileSavePath);
        }

        logger.LogDownloadCompleted(e.IsSuccess, _elapsedTime, isCancelled);
        logger.LogDownloadCancelled();
    }

    if (downloadsCounter == 0)
    {
        logger.LogDownloadCompleted();
        Download.Enabled = true;
    }

    logger.GetLog(richTextBoxLogger);
}
```

`

The completed Logger class code:

```
// Logger.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logging_Test
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        private TimeSpan elapsedTime; // Add a private variable to store elapsed time

        public void LogStartDownload(string fileName, string fileUrl)
        {
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Start Time]: {DateTime.Now}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[File Name]: {fileName}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[File URL]: {fileUrl}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Status] Downloading in progress");
        }

        public void LogDownloadProgress(double percentage, double speed, long totalBytes, long contentLength, TimeSpan elapsedTime)
        {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Store elapsed time for later use
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Progress]: {percentage}%");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Downloaded]: {FormatBytes(totalBytes)} / {FormatBytes(contentLength)}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Download Speed]: {FormatBytes(speed)}/s");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Time Elapsed]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}");
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted(bool isSuccess, TimeSpan elapsedTime, bool isCancelled)
        {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Update elapsed time when the download completes
            if (!isCancelled)
            {
                logBuilder.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}");
                //logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}");
            }
            else
            {
                logBuilder.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download Cancelled");
                //logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Status]: Download Cancelled");
            }
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Elapsed Time]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"[End Time]: {DateTime.Now}");
            logBuilder.AppendLine(); // Add a space line between download logs
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted()
        {
            logBuilder.AppendLine("[Status]: All downloads completed");
            logBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        public void LogDownloadCancelled()
        {
            logBuilder.AppendLine("[Status]: Operation cancelled and all file have been deleted");
            logBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        public string GetLog(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
        {
            string log = logBuilder.ToString();
            richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(log);
            logBuilder.Clear(); // Clear the log after appending it once

            return log;
        }

        private string FormatBytes(double bytes)
        {
            const int scale = 1024;
            string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };

            if (bytes <= 0)
            {
                return "0 B";
            }

            int magnitude = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, scale));
            int index = Math.Min(magnitude, units.Length - 1);

            double adjustedSize = bytes / Math.Pow(scale, index);
            string format = (index >= 0 && index < 3) ? "F2" : "F0";

            return $"{adjustedSize.ToString(format)} {units[index]}";
        }

        private string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return $"{timeSpan.Hours:D2}:{timeSpan.Minutes:D2}:{timeSpan.Seconds:D2}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if you put breakpoints on all the `logBuilder.Replace` calls, and you step through one of them, the call doesn't do what it's supposed to?

Comment: @user246821 How would events change anything here?

Comment: This is nothing to do with threads @derloopkat and this is already using an event pattern so that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder.Replace()` is working as expected here, the problem is that your `GetLog()` method is clearing out the string builder, so there is nothing to replace.

So if you never call `GetLog()` then your replace logic will work, but seeing that you will likely want to display the progress messages, I suspect that your progress from the `DownloadManager` is also calling `GetLog()`

```
public string GetLog(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
{
    string log = logBuilder.ToString();
    richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(log);
    logBuilder.Clear(); // Clear the log after appending it once

    return log;
}
```

Your `richTextBoxLogger` is where you are actually *seeing* the logs, but it does not show the content of the `logBuilder`.

Here is a fiddle to show what happens if you comment out the line that clears the log: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WGDCNi

The output looks like this:

```
Start Download:
[Start Time]: 12/30/2023 00:42:00
[File Name]: log.txt
[File URL]: ~/its_just_a_test/log.txt
[Status] Downloading in progress

Show Progress 20%:
[Start Time]: 12/30/2023 00:42:00
[File Name]: log.txt
[File URL]: ~/its_just_a_test/log.txt
[Status] Downloading in progress
[Progress]: 20%
[Downloaded]: 8.28 KB / 41.40 KB
[Download Speed]: 471.00 B/s
[Time Elapsed]: 00:00:18

Show Progress 80%:
[Start Time]: 12/30/2023 00:42:00
[File Name]: log.txt
[File URL]: ~/its_just_a_test/log.txt
[Status] Downloading in progress
[Progress]: 20%
[Downloaded]: 8.28 KB / 41.40 KB
[Download Speed]: 471.00 B/s
[Time Elapsed]: 00:00:18
[Progress]: 80%
[Downloaded]: 33.12 KB / 41.40 KB
[Download Speed]: 440.00 B/s
[Time Elapsed]: 00:01:17

Show Complete
[Start Time]: 12/30/2023 00:42:00
[File Name]: log.txt
[File URL]: ~/its_just_a_test/log.txt
[Status]: Download Completed Successfully
[Progress]: 20%
[Downloaded]: 8.28 KB / 41.40 KB
[Download Speed]: 471.00 B/s
[Time Elapsed]: 00:00:18
[Progress]: 80%
[Downloaded]: 33.12 KB / 41.40 KB
[Download Speed]: 440.00 B/s
[Time Elapsed]: 00:01:17
[Elapsed Time]: 00:01:49
[End Time]: 12/30/2023 00:42:00
```

You can see that in the final entry the status has changed:

```
[Status]: Download Completed Successfully
```

---

Traditionally a Log is only appended to, each line or entry in the log records the *state* or *status* at a given point in time.

> **LOG**  (*verb*)
> enter (an incident or fact) in the log of a ship or aircraft or in another systematic record.

What you are actually doing here is showing the *current status* of the download that includes some log entries, but you are mostly concerned about the *current* state.

A better way to do this is to create a class that represents the state, and to generate the log string from the instance variables on demand instead of manipulation of a string that you are changing over time. It is a novel approach but a lot more effort and harder to extend than it needs to be. I know you are not asking for a code review, but it does need to be said ;)

The other major anti-pattern here is that you are passing in a reference to the UI control to a domain class to manipulate. In this type of code your *code behind* class for the `Form` should be the only class that interacts with the controls *on* that form.

This tightly couples your `Logger` to require a `RichTextBox` to exist at all. It is an unnecessary requirement that will make your code harder to maintain over time.

So what do I think this *should* look like? `DownloadManager` really should have all of the *state* values contained within it and you would use those properties to build a new status report when the progress changes, or for a more efficient user interface, you call it periodically from the UI.

Something like this is a better approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GwkNVd Still not great, but takes what you have learned and guides you in a new direction... closer to MVVM :)