# How to color specific lines in richTextBox in specific color depending on the color setting when using StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a logger module file class and in the class I extended it and added my own custom `StringBuilder` and I want to be able easy to color lines in the richTextBox1 control in form1 designer depending on the color setting in the Logger class for each `StringBuilder` line.

In the class `Logger` I extended the class to use my own custom `StringBuilder` with a color property.

```
// Logger.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger_Testing
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger;
        private CustomStringBuilder sb = new CustomStringBuilder();

        public Logger(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
        {
            this.richTextBoxLogger = richTextBoxLogger;
        }

        public void LogStartDownload(string fileName, string fileUrl)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"[Start Time]: {DateTime.Now}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[File Name]: {fileName}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[File URL]: {fileUrl}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Status] Downloading in progress", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadProgress(double percentage, double speed, long totalBytes, long contentLength, TimeSpan elapsedTime)
        {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Store elapsed time for later use
            sb.AppendLine($"[Progress]: {percentage}%", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Downloaded]: {FormatBytes(totalBytes)} / {FormatBytes(contentLength)}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Download Speed]: {FormatBytes(speed)}/s", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Time Elapsed]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted(bool isSuccess, TimeSpan elapsedTime, bool isCancelled)
        {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Update elapsed time when the download completes

            if (!isCancelled)
            {
                sb.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}", Color.Yellow);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download Cancelled", Color.Red);
            }

            sb.AppendLine($"[Elapsed Time]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[End Time]: {DateTime.Now}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow); // Add a space line between download logs
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted()
        {
            sb.AppendLine("[Status]: All downloads completed", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadCancelled()
        {
            sb.AppendLine("[Status]: Operation cancelled and all file have been deleted", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public string GetLog(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
        {
            richTextBoxLogger.Clear();
            string log = sb.ToString();
            richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(log); // Set RichTextBox text as RTF to preserve formatting
            //logBuilder.Clear(); // Clear the log after appending it once

            return log;
        }

        private string FormatBytes(double bytes)
        {
            const int scale = 1024;
            string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };

            if (bytes <= 0)
            {
                return "0 B";
            }

            int magnitude = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, scale));
            int index = Math.Min(magnitude, units.Length - 1);

            double adjustedSize = bytes / Math.Pow(scale, index);
            string format = (index >= 0 && index < 3) ? "F2" : "F0";

            return $"{adjustedSize.ToString(format)} {units[index]}";
        }

        private string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return $"{timeSpan.Hours:D2}:{timeSpan.Minutes:D2}:{timeSpan.Seconds:D2}";
        }

        public void Replace(string oldText, string newText, Color textColor)
        {
            sb.Replace(oldText, newText, textColor);
            UpdateRichTextBox();
        }

        private void UpdateRichTextBox()
        {
            richTextBoxLogger.Clear();

            foreach (var line in sb.Lines)
            {
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionStart = richTextBoxLogger.TextLength;
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionLength = 0;
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionColor = line.Color;
                richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(line.Text + "\n");
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionColor = richTextBoxLogger.ForeColor; // Reset color
            }
        }

        public class CustomStringBuilder
        {
            public List<CustomStringBuilderItem> Lines { get; } = new List<CustomStringBuilderItem>();

            public void AppendLine(string text, Color color)
            {
                Lines.Add(new CustomStringBuilderItem { Text = text, Color = color });
            }

            public void Replace(string oldText, string newText, Color textColor)
            {
                var line = Lines.Find(l => l.Text.Contains(oldText));

                if (line != null)
                {
                    line.Text = line.Text.Replace(oldText, newText);
                    line.Color = textColor;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var line in Lines)
                {
                    result.AppendLine(line.Text);
                }

                return result.ToString();
            }
        }

        public class CustomStringBuilderItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public Color Color { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

For example this line I want it to be colored in Red in the richTextBox1 I have in the form1 designer:

```
sb.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download Cancelled", Color.Red);
```

This is how I'm using it in form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger_Testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Logger logger;
        private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            logger = new Logger(richTextBox1);

            logger.LogStartDownload("Hello", "Hello World");
            logger.GetLog(richTextBox1);
        }

        private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logger.LogDownloadCompleted(false, _elapsedTime, true);
            logger.LogDownloadCancelled();

            logger.GetLog(richTextBox1);
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is when I click the button to replace the text is that the replaced text is also in yellow like all the rest of the text in the richTextBox1 and not in red for the specific replace line.

The line "[Status]: Download Cancelled" should be colored in red.

[image: All the text is in yellow but the line [Status]: Download Cancelled should be colored in red]

Comment: try adding the text before setting the color and use the text length for the selection length. you now apply the color to a portion of lenght=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have not noticed is that *none* of your color logic is working. If you set the default forecolor on the rich text box to *Black*, (or any color other than yellow) or leave it in the default state as I did, then you will not see any yellow text at all.

The first step to debugging this would be to put a break point in the `UpdateRichTextBox()` method:
[image: Setting break point in UpdateRichTextBox]
when you run the app, this method is never entered, we follow the references back a step, the replace method before it is the only method that calls `UpdateRichTextBox` but it is never called itself:

[image: Highlight references to Replace]

I suspect you meant to replace all other references of `sb.Replace()` with this method instead. But this is needlessly rewriting the rich text box for every change, when you really only need to do it at the end of each bulk set of operations.

I recommend then that you remove this method:

```
   public void Replace(string oldText, string newText, Color textColor)
   {
       sb.Replace(oldText, newText, textColor);
       UpdateRichTextBox();
   }
```

And instead call `UpdateRichTextBox()` at the end of each method that manipulates the string builder, currently `GetLog` is already called by convention after all the operations, so we only need to put this method call in there...

[image: Convention of calling GetLog]

which highlights another flaw in this logic, it doesn't matter if we fix the previous bug in other ways, every time that you call `GetLog()`, it is currently going to clear the rich text box.

The comment on this line is a true statement:

```
richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(log); // Set RichTextBox text as RTF to preserve formatting
```

But that is dependent on the string you provide to the rich text box as being RTF (Rich Text Format) in the first place. Your output from your `CustomStringBuilder` is however plain text and does not contain any RTF markup formatting at all, more on this later...

So this quick fix to all this is to recognise that `GetLog` and `UpdateRichTextBox` were always conceptually meant to do the same thing, `GetLog` was your original attempt that requires a reference to the Rich Text editor to be passed in, `UpdateRichTextBox` is your new attempt that uses an internal reference to the rich text box and just hasn't been fully hooked up yet. The quick fix is to merge the two methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears the <paramref name="richTextBoxLogger"/> and appends the with the
/// contents of the internal <see cref="CustomStringBuilder"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="richTextBoxLogger">
/// RichTextBox to write to, if null, will default to the 
/// RichTextBox that was provided in the constructor to this <seealso cref="Logger"/>
/// </param>
public void UpdateRichTextBox(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
{
    // I would choose either member reference or local reference, doesn't add much value to support both.
    // My personal vote would be to NOT have a member reference, unless this method is on the Form class.
    if (richTextBoxLogger == null) richTextBoxLogger = this.richTextBoxLogger;

    richTextBoxLogger.Clear();

    foreach (var line in sb.Lines)
    {
        richTextBoxLogger.SelectionStart = richTextBoxLogger.TextLength;
        richTextBoxLogger.SelectionLength = 0;
        richTextBoxLogger.SelectionColor = line.Color;
        richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(line.Text + "\n");
        richTextBoxLogger.SelectionColor = richTextBoxLogger.ForeColor; // Reset color
    }
}
```

You can see my commentary in that code, there is not a lot of value in passing the text box in to the constructor for this class unless it was going to autonomously refresh the textbox when your string builder changed. But this simple change, and updating the references in the form class will make your user interface work:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        logger = new Logger(richTextBox1);

        logger.LogStartDownload("Hello", "Hello World");
        logger.UpdateRichTextBox(richTextBox1);
    }

    private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logger.LogDownloadCompleted(false, _elapsedTime, true);
        logger.LogDownloadCancelled();

        logger.UpdateRichTextBox(richTextBox1);
    }
```

[image: proof is in the pudding]

But is this what you wanted? Probably not, you probably wanted to add the call to `UpdateRichTextBox` to each of the other public logger methods. I don't want to encourage that, but you are welcome to do it on your own. The reason that I don't want to encourage that is that it further couples your concept of logging and rendering the log to your specific UI. It's just a bad habit to get into.

### So what is RTF anyway and how could it be used?

I'm glad you asked. RTF is a plain text markup language like HTML and GitHub Markdown, it has specific syntax to contain metadata that can be used to format the text as it is rendered.

This for example is captured after clicking the button, in RTF. (We can access this from the rich text control itself: `Console.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Rtf);`

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;\red253\green245\blue230;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\cf1\f0\fs18 [Start Time]: 31/12/2023 1:11:03 PM\par
[File Name]: Hello\par
[File URL]: Hello World\par
\cf2 [Status]: Download Cancelled\par
\cf1 [Elapsed Time]: 00:00:00\par
[End Time]: 31/12/2023 1:11:06 PM\par
\par
[Status]: Operation cancelled and all file have been deleted\par
\par
\cf3\par
}
```

I won't go into too much detail, read this if you are interested: [RTF Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/dist/RTF-Writer/view/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod), but you might be able to see from this that RTF has similarities to HTML with *styles*. Just like HTML, in RTF you *can* specify style references in-line, however the RichTextBox groups the fonts and colors into reference tables and uses shorthand syntax to reference the style for the lines that need it.

Back to your comment:

```
richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(log); // Set RichTextBox text as RTF to preserve formatting
```

If your `log` contained markup like above, then AppendText would preserve that, you could also set the text via the [`RichTextBox.Rtf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) property, that would preserve any RTF and be the same as clearing the textbox and appending the RTF markup.

Conversely, when you set the [`RichTextbox.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) the text is *encoded* so that any RTF syntax is *escaped*.

This means that you could use a similar solution [one I proposed in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734635/1690217) to de-couple the building of the log message from a reference to the user control. Or as you have already extended the `String Builder` lets take that and add to it for support basic RTF, HTML and GitHub Markdown... Why would you bother, normally you wouldn't because these types of encapsulations already exist in the .Net framework and in existing thirdparty libraries, but it is an interesting learning experiment on why you would abstract the logic in this way and how you can create a component that might be useful to you in other projects, such is the goal of a X10 developer ;)

This is the new `ColoredStringBuilder`

```
public class ColoredStringBuilderItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class ColoredStringBuilder
{
    public List<ColoredStringBuilderItem> Lines { get; } = new List<ColoredStringBuilderItem>();

    public void AppendLine(string text, Color color)
    {
        Lines.Add(new ColoredStringBuilderItem { Text = text, Color = color });
    }

    public void Replace(string oldText, string newText, Color textColor)
    {
        var line = Lines.Find(l => l.Text.Contains(oldText));

        if (line != null)
        {
            line.Text = line.Text.Replace(oldText, newText);
            line.Color = textColor;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(TextFormat.Plain);
    }

    public string ToString(TextFormat format)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        // build the color tables, we can use this in RTF and HTML
        List<string> colorDefinitions = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<Color, string> colorReferenceMap = new Dictionary<Color, string>();
        var colors = Lines.GroupBy(x => x.Color).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        foreach (var color in colors)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case TextFormat.RTF:
                    string reference = $"\\cf{colorReferenceMap.Count + 1}";
                    colorReferenceMap.Add(color, reference);
                    colorDefinitions.Add($"\\red{color.R}\\green{color.G}\\blue{color.B}");
                    break;

                case TextFormat.HTML:
                    string className = $"cf{colorReferenceMap.Count + 1}";
                    colorReferenceMap.Add(color, className);
                    colorDefinitions.Add($".{className} {{ color: #{color.R:x2}{color.G:x2}{color.B:x2}; }}");
                    break;

                case TextFormat.Markdown:
                    // make Red use block quote?
                    if (color == Color.Red)
                        colorReferenceMap.Add(color, "> ");
                    else
                        colorReferenceMap.Add(color, "");
                    break;
            }
        }

        // inject the styles
        switch (format)
        {
            case TextFormat.RTF:
                // preamble
                result.AppendLine("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil Segoe UI;}}");
                result.AppendLine($"{{\\colortbl;{String.Join(";", colorDefinitions)};}}");
                result.AppendLine(@"{\*\generator ColoredStringBuilder 1.0.0}\viewkind4\uc1");
                break;
            case TextFormat.HTML:
                    result.Append("<html><head>");
                result.AppendLine("<style>");
                foreach (var style in colorDefinitions)
                    result.AppendLine(style);
                result.AppendLine("</style>");
                result.AppendLine("</head>");
                result.AppendLine("<body>");
                break;
        }

        foreach (var line in Lines)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case TextFormat.Plain:
                    result.AppendLine(line.Text);
                    break;
                case TextFormat.RTF:
                    result.Append(colorReferenceMap[line.Color]);
                    result.Append(line.Text);
                    result.Append("\\par");
                    result.AppendLine();
                    break;
                case TextFormat.HTML:
                    result.Append($"<span class=\"{colorReferenceMap[line.Color]}\">");
                    result.Append(line.Text);
                    result.Append("</span></br>");
                    result.AppendLine();
                    break;
                case TextFormat.Markdown:
                    result.Append(colorReferenceMap[line.Color]);
                    result.Append(line.Text);
                    result.AppendLine("  "); // creates a single line break in the current paragraph
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException($"Have not yet implemented support for format: {format}");
            }
        }

        // close the document
        switch (format)
        {
            case TextFormat.RTF:
                // preamble
                result.AppendLine(@"}");
                break;
            case TextFormat.HTML:
                result.AppendLine("</body>");
                result.AppendLine("</html>");
                break;
        }


        return result.ToString();
    }

}

public enum TextFormat
{
    Plain,
    RTF,
    Markdown,
    HTML
}
```

`GetLog` now just calls through to the string builder and passes the format

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the contents of the internal <see cref="CustomStringBuilder"/>
/// formatted int the requested markdown <paramref name="format"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="format">The markdown format for the log</param>
public string GetLog(TextFormat format = TextFormat.Plain)
{
    return sb.ToString(format);
}
```

`Form1` now looks like this, notice we do not need to pass a reference to the text box at all.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Logger logger;
    private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        logger = new Logger(richTextBox1);

        logger.LogStartDownload("Hello", "Hello World");
        richTextBox1.Rtf = logger.GetLog(Logger.TextFormat.RTF);
    }

    private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logger.LogDownloadCompleted(false, _elapsedTime, true);
        logger.LogDownloadCancelled();

        richTextBox1.Rtf = logger.GetLog(Logger.TextFormat.RTF);

        Debug.WriteLine(logger.GetLog(Logger.TextFormat.HTML));
        Debug.WriteLine(logger.GetLog(Logger.TextFormat.Markdown));
    }
}
```

You can see the HTML and Markdown outputs in the debugger for a bit of fun ;)

---

I can see you're going to ask a few more questions based on this code, it is good that you are posting as separate questions but to get the most out of this platform you should reduce your code examples to a minimum representation.

Questions with this much code are hard for the wider community to relate to, especially when the title doesn't really correlate to the actual issue you are experiencing. In this case you write code that worked, but it was never called. Had you taken the time to write a [[MRE]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you would have probably identified this and solved the issue yourself.

I have tried to make this answer constructive and relevant in a way that might help other developers who has similar issues, but the reality is that this problem was so specific to your codebase that other users on Stack Overflow are not likely to see it at all, when they do they may not see the value in it or in contributing to what is now becoming a code review discussion...

You might in the future consider posting in https://codereview.stackexchange.com to gain guidance on the style and complexity of the code that you do write.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure with your replace logic but here is a ready to use `ColorRichTextBox` control that **adds a colored line** with the `AddLine()` method:

```cs
public class ColorRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public ColorRichTextBox()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Black;
        Font = new Font("Consolas", 12);
        ReadOnly = true;
    }

    public void AddLine(string text, Color color)
    {
        AppendText(text);
        int firstcharindex = GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        Select(firstcharindex, text.Length);
        SelectionColor = color;
        DeselectAll();
        Select(Text.Length, 0);
        AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Add a `ColorRichTextBox` instance to your form designer and fill it like

```
colorRichTextBox1.AddLine("Download started...", Color.Yellow);
colorRichTextBox1.AddLine("Download cancelled.", Color.Red);
```

The result will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my working code:

```
// Logger.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger_Testing
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private CustomStringBuilder sb;
        private TimeSpan elapsedTime; // Add a private variable to store elapsed time
        private bool isCancelled = false;

        public Logger()
        {
            this.sb = new CustomStringBuilder();
        }

        public void LogStartDownload(string fileName, string fileUrl)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"[Start Time]: {DateTime.Now}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[File Name]: {fileName}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[File URL]: {fileUrl}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Status] Downloading in progress", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadProgress(double percentage, double speed, long totalBytes, long contentLength, TimeSpan elapsedTime)
        {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Store elapsed time for later use
            sb.AppendLine($"[Progress]: {percentage}%", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Downloaded]: {FormatBytes(totalBytes)} / {FormatBytes(contentLength)}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Download Speed]: {FormatBytes(speed)}/s", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[Time Elapsed]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted(bool isSuccess, TimeSpan elapsedTime, bool isCancelled)
        {
            this.isCancelled = isCancelled;

            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime; // Update elapsed time when the download completes
            if (!isCancelled)
            {
                sb.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}", Color.Yellow);
                //logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Status]: Download {(isSuccess ? "Completed Successfully" : "Failed")}");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Replace($"[Status] Downloading in progress", $"[Status]: Download Cancelled", Color.Red);
                //logBuilder.AppendLine($"[Status]: Download Cancelled");
            }
            sb.AppendLine($"[Elapsed Time]: {FormatTimeSpan(elapsedTime)}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine($"[End Time]: {DateTime.Now}", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow); // Add a space line between download logs
        }

        public void LogDownloadCompleted()
        {
            sb.AppendLine("[Status]: All downloads completed", Color.Yellow);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow);
        }

        public void LogDownloadCancelled()
        {
            sb.AppendLine("[Status]: Operation cancelled and all file have been deleted", Color.Red);
            sb.AppendLine("", Color.Yellow);
        }


        public string GetLog(RichTextBox richTextBoxLogger)
        {
            richTextBoxLogger.Clear();
            var lines = sb.Lines; // Get the lines from CustomStringBuilder

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                int startIndex = richTextBoxLogger.TextLength; // Start from the end

                richTextBoxLogger.AppendText(line.Text + Environment.NewLine); // Append the line

                // Select the line and apply the specified color
                richTextBoxLogger.Select(startIndex, line.Text.Length);
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionColor = line.Color;

                // Deselect the text
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionStart = richTextBoxLogger.TextLength;
                richTextBoxLogger.SelectionLength = 0;
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string FormatBytes(double bytes)
        {
            const int scale = 1024;
            string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };

            if (bytes <= 0)
            {
                return "0 B";
            }

            int magnitude = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, scale));
            int index = Math.Min(magnitude, units.Length - 1);

            double adjustedSize = bytes / Math.Pow(scale, index);
            string format = (index >= 0 && index < 3) ? "F2" : "F0";

            return $"{adjustedSize.ToString(format)} {units[index]}";
        }

        private string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return $"{timeSpan.Hours:D2}:{timeSpan.Minutes:D2}:{timeSpan.Seconds:D2}";
        }

        public class CustomStringBuilder
        {
           

            public List<CustomStringBuilderItem> Lines { get; } = new List<CustomStringBuilderItem>();

            public void AppendLine(string text, Color color)
            {
                Lines.Add(new CustomStringBuilderItem { Text = text, Color = color });
            }

            public void Replace(string oldText, string newText, Color textColor)
            {
                var line = Lines.Find(l => l.Text.Contains(oldText));
                if (line != null)
                {
                    line.Text = line.Text.Replace(oldText, newText);
                    line.Color = textColor;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var line in Lines)
                {
                    result.AppendLine(line.Text);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }

        public class CustomStringBuilderItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public Color Color { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and form1 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger_Testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Logger logger;
        private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            logger = new Logger();

            logger.LogStartDownload("Hello", "Hello World");
            logger.GetLog(richTextBox1);
        }

        private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logger.LogDownloadCompleted(false, _elapsedTime, true);
            logger.LogDownloadCancelled();

            logger.GetLog(richTextBox1);
        }
    }
}
```